# Netbeans GUI add buttons using if statement

Tags: java, swing, button, netbeans

I am creating a Java GUI using Netbeans GUI creator.

And I want to add buttons to a panel using a if statement,
ive done this many times before, but not with Netbeans.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                          if (something){
                              String files = something.getName();
                              JButton btn = new JButton(files);
                              panel.add(btn);
                              panel.validate();
```

This is the if statement which worked when I didn't use Netbeans GUI maker.
But now nothing is displayed, and no errors appear.

this is how the panel is created

```
public final javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

       javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
```

Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: Could be any number of things. Assuming you're using a layout manager add `panel.repaint()` after the validate call. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Reimeus I added how panel is created

Comment: You're using `GroupLayout`. Any new buttons will have to be added using the correct horizontal & vertical groups.

Comment: Thankyou, I changed it to flowlayout, and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupLayout` requires that any new buttons/comooinents be added using the correct horizontal & vertical groups. Alternatively, you can use a different layout manager which does not require any constraints to be set on newly added components. These include `FlowLayout` and `GridLayout`.